# Запись в БД из Recyclerview

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется `RecyclerView`, в котором есть поля. Как организовать считывание данных и запись в БД?

```
public class TableMain extends Activity {

    List<TableModel> tableModels = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_main);


        createObjectTable();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        DataAdapter dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(this, tableModels);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }

    public void createObjectTable() {
        tableModels.add(new TableModel("", "", ""));
        tableModels.add(new TableModel("", "", ""));
    }
}


class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<TableModel> tableModels;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<TableModel> tableModels) {
        this.tableModels = tableModels;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_table_model, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tableModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        EditText task, firstMark, secondMark;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           task = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_EditText);
           firstMark = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_mark_EditText);
           secondMark = itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_mark_EditText);
        }
   }
}

public class TableModel {

    private String task;
    private String firstMark;
    private String secondMark;

    public TableModel(String task, String firstMark, String secondMark) {
        this.task = task;
        this.firstMark = firstMark;
        this.secondMark = secondMark;
    }

    public String getTask() {

        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public String getFirstMark() {
        return firstMark;
    }

    public void setFirstMark(String firstMark) {
        this.firstMark = firstMark;
    }

    public String getSecondMark() {
        return secondMark;
    }

    public void setSecondMark(String secondMark) {
        this.secondMark = secondMark;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавте код как текст вместо картинки.

Comment: Добавил код классов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эммм... это такой обширный вопрос. Принято это делать так:

1) Нужен `ContentProvider`, над вашей БД - можно и без него, но это как бы не очень кошерно

2) Далее надо научиться асинхронно загружать из `ContentProvider`'а `Cursor`, делается это посредством `CursorLoader`

3) Когда у вас появится `Cursor` уже можно применить [RecyclerViewCursorAdapter](https://github.com/androidessence/RecyclerViewCursorAdapter) - ну то есть адаптер, который автоматом будет на каждую запись БД отображать айтем в  `RecyclerView`

4) Теперь в холдере у вас будет `Cursor`, который будет указывать на текущую запись, соответственно можно будет его апдейтить прямо из `ViewHolder`

Как то так.

Можно пропустить шаги 1, 2 и сразу получить `Cursor` из БД посредством `SQLiteDatabase.query()`, будет не так красиво и немного подтормаживать, но вполне работоспособно.